# How to access STK application from J2ME

Tags: java-me, mobile, sim-card

*I've been through this site and many others multiple times but to no avail. So am forced to post a fresh new question here. Is it possible access a SIM loaded STK application from a j2me app running on the phone?*

Answer (score 0):

(JSR-177) Security and Trust Services API has an optional package called SATSA-APDU you can use this API to exchange messages with the SIM card. This [chapter](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/security/satsa-dg/apdu.html) from the SATSA guide explains how to use it.